# R merge "can't allocate region"

Tags: r

I have two data frames:

```
name type       length size    value
x    data.frame 2      152.6MB 20,000,263 obs of 2 variables
y    data.frame 26     2.2GB   20,000,263 obs of 26 variables
```

when doing

```
x <- merge(x,y, by="common variable")
```

I receive the following error:

```
rsession(25305,0x7fff7c8e9300) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=1600042080280576) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
rsession(25305,0x7fff7c8e9300) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=1600042080280576) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1490155.3 Gb
```

I can't think of any reason why R is trying to allocate 1,490,155.3Gb worth of space...

Anyone got perhaps have some insight into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the way this is done is to store all the combinations of the matching variable in `a` and `b` and then select the ones where it matches. It does require lots of memory. This line here (from `merge.data.frame`) looks like it would do that:

```
ij <- expand.grid(seq_len(nx), seq_len(ny))
```

where `nx` and `ny` are the row counts of your data frames. So here this is trying to create something that is 20,000,000 by 20,000,000 x 2 elements in size, which is probably going to get into the zillions of Gb of RAM needed.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any advice on how I can get around this? My nature of the data means that it is all in the correct order i.e row 132 in set x corresponds to row 132 in y

Comment: `cbind(x,y)`? Check on a tiny sample first.

Comment: Ha, thanks! Took 2 seconds to do it on the full data set. Not sure why I didn't think of that...